# Short circuit logical operators over Iterable

Tags: java, logical-operators, short-circuiting

Consider the following code, the loop can finish as soon as it hits a `false` value. Is there a better way than checking for `false` after each iteration?

```
boolean result = true;
List<Boolean> bList = new ArrayList<>();
for (boolean b : bList) {
    result = result && b;
    if (!result) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Stream.allMatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#allMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) which is a short-circuiting operation.

```
List<Boolean> bList = new ArrayList<>();
boolean result = bList.stream().allMatch(b -> b);
```

Answer (score 4):

What about

```
if (bList.contains(false)) {
  ...
```

Comment: See my answer for a more general solution that allows you to evaluate a predicate over any type of `Iterable`.

Comment: That approach may be more generic but its functionality is not as obvious..:)

Answer (score 1):

Consider extracting the loop to its method:

```
boolean allTrue(List<Boolean> bools) {
  for (boolean b : bools)
    if (!b)
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```